# Proof of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $F$ be a field and let $(V, +, F)$ be a vector space over $F$. If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $F$, prove that $W_1 - W_2 = \{v \in V | v = w_1 - w_2 \text{ for some } w_1 \in W_1, w_2 \in W_2 \}$ is a subspace of $V$.

To be clear, I know that $0$ is an element of $W_1,W_2$ because both are subspaces, so $0$ is also an element of $W_1-W_2$. I know both are closed under scalar multiplication and addition because of the same reason. So how would I show $W_1-W_2$ is closed under scalar multiplication and addition?

Comment: You are almost there, just write everything out.  For scalar multiplication say, note that $\lambda\left(w_1-w_2\right)=\lambda\,w_1-\lambda\,w_2$.  For addition, suppose you took two elements in your "formal difference":  $w_1-w_2,\;\omega_1-\omega_2$.  Add these to get...

Comment: (w1 + omega1) - (w2 + omega2)?

Comment: Perfect.  To be complete, you should check additive inverses.

Comment: Would that be in this case (w2-w1) where w2 is still an element of W2 and w1 is still an element of W1?

Comment: Well, yes...but you have to argue that this is an element of your formal difference.  We know the additive inverse exists as an element of $V$ but you have to prove it can be written in your form.

Comment: So since each additive inverse exists because each element of the formal difference is from a subspace, can I write (-w1 - (-w2)) instead, where -w1 is the additive inverse of w1 in W1 and -w2 is the additive inverse of w2 in W2?

Comment: You got it.  If you want to dig deeper, suppose you had an explicit basis for each of $W_1$ and $W_2$.  Find one for the difference.

Comment: Hmmmm. Would it be the basis for both subspaces?

Comment: Be explicit...if $\omega_i$ is a basis for $W_1$, for $1≤i≤m$ and $\nu_j$ is a basis for $W_2$ for $1≤j≤n$, what is your proposed basis?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27622/discussion-between-lulu-and-jay3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great [link](http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-S.html) to verify your work.

If I were you, I would try demonstrating the $W=W_1-W_2 \neq \emptyset$ by showing an element which is in it. Here is a hint:

> We know that since $W_1, W_2$ are subspace that $0 \in W$. Since $0 = 0 - 0 \in V$ because $0 \in W_1, W_2$.

And further, step 2:

> Let $x \in W$ and $y \in W$, then $x = w_1 - w_2$, $y=w_3 -w_4$ for some $w_1, w_2 \in W_1, w_3, w_4 \in W_2$. And further, $x+y = (w_1-w_2)-(w_4-w_3) \in W$, since $W_i$ is a subspace.

Step 3:

> Let $a \in \mathbb{F}$, then $av \in W$; since $av =a(w_1 -w_2)=aw_1-aw_2$ for some $w_1, w_2 \in W_1, W_2$. This is because $W_i$ is a subspace, i.e. a vector space.